# Magento Products on multistore category going to default store

Tags: magento, multistore

I just set up a multistore site in Magento. I am using a subdirectory. example.com/store2. The category links all go to /store2 but the products on the category pages all go to example.com/product.html. How can I get them to go to example.com/store2/product.html

Thanks

Comment: By using magentos inbuilt multistore functionality and not putting another instance in a subdirectory. See http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/stores-multiple.html for more info

Comment: Thanks Ash. I am using magento multistore but I either need to use a new domain, a subdomain or a subdirectory correct? I have chosen to do a subdirectory but to use the same categories as the main site. Are you saying using a different domain or a subdomain would make it so clicking on the product on a category page would not take the user to the product on the main site?

Comment: I guess you don't need to use a subdirectory, new domain or subdomain. If all you do is add a new store view name this will add a drop down menu in the header and magento cookies will do the work for you. Thanks